# Shudra learning and chanting Vedas

Tags: vedas, shudra

Does below say Shudras can learn Vedas?

YathA imAm vAcham kalyAnim AvadAni janebhyah (1)
BrahmarAjanyAbhyAm sudrAya cha AryAya cha (2)
SwAya cha aranAya cha (3)

Meaning

May i speak the sacred word to the masses of the people (janebhya) (1) to the brahmana, kshatriya, to the sudra and the Arya (2) and to our own men and the strangers (3).

Shukla Yajur Veda 26.2

And,

Sukla Yajurveda (XXVI. 2).

यथेमां वाचं कल्याणीमावदानि जनेभ्यःब्रह्मराजन्याभ्यां शूद्राय चार्याय च स्वाय चारणाय॥ Meaning- The way I gave this knowledge of Vedas for benefit of all humans, similarly you all also propagate the same for benefit of Brahmins, Kshatriyas, Shudras, Vaishyas, Women and even most downtrodden. The scholars and the wealthy people should ensure that they not deviate from this message of mine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How have traditional Vedic commentators interpreted Shukla Yajurveda 26.2?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31514/how-have-traditional-vedic-commentators-interpreted-shukla-yajurveda-26-2)